# Show exact number of CRLF occurrences in file

Tags: text-processing, grep, newlines

`grep -c $'\r\n' file` returns the exact same number as `grep -c $'\n' file`, it shows the number of LF in the file instead of the number of CRLF. (The file definitely does not contain that number of CRLF.) How can I determine the exact number of CRLF occurrences?

I've tried the following commands, none of them return the right number:

```
grep -c $'\r\n' file
grep -c $"\r\n" file
grep -c '\r\n' file
grep -c "\r\n" file
```

Comment: Why not `grep -c "\r\n" file` ?

Comment: Tried various combinations of with and without the dollar sign, and using single or double quotes, none of them return the right number.

Comment: Try `grep -c "^M$" sample.txt` (Note that `^M` is `Ctrl+v,Ctrl+m`)

Answer (score 5):

The pattern argument to grep is in fact a newline-separated list of patterns. Thus `grep $'\r\n'` searches either a CR or the empty pattern (which matches every line). This is the same as `grep $'\n'` which searches the empty pattern or the empty pattern.

To search for a CRLF sequence, search for a CR at the end of the line.

```
grep -c $'\r$' file
```

Comment: With the tiny exception of files where last byte is a `\r`.

Comment: @user367890 If the last byte isn't a newline then the file isn't a text file, so the behavior depends on the grep implementation. With GNU grep, `grep $'\r$'` does find a CR at the end of the file.